# Get transcription from call in twilio ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I am initializing a record through xml

```
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |response|
  response.say(message: message)
  response.enqueue workflowSid: 'sid'
end
twiml.record(transcribe: true)
render xml: twiml.to_xml
```

After the call is finished I want to retrieve the transcription,

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_account_sid, twilio_authentication_key)
```

I can retrieve the call log

```
call = client.calls(params[:call_sid])
rec = call.recordings()
```

But I cannot find how to retrieve the transcription.

Comment: Your `<Record>` is being placed in the TwiML after the `<Enqueue>` so it won't get triggered (the caller will be directed to the workflow instead and won't start recording). `<Record>` is used for features like voicemail, are you trying to record the entire call and interaction between agent and caller?

Comment: Yes I want to record the call between agent and caller, how can I do that?

Comment: I’d recommend you start with this article: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010199074-Getting-Started-with-Call-Recording-Controls. Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the transcription callback.

`transcribeCallback`
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback